# Find big primes numbers (~8000 Digits) in a given range

Tags: java, primes, biginteger

I am writting a code in java to find prime numbers but to find the next one i need to use this prime number with 8761 digits [P] (found using this code) and one other prime number smaller than P in a given range, right now i am looking for prime numbers within a distance of 250 millions.

The problem is finding all the prime numbers inside this range. Using a sieve of erasthostenes i got from 125M (odd numbers) to 6 million probable primes before it got slow. But that is a far as i got.

Since BigInteger's .isPrime(1) takes 3 min for EACH number i would have kids in the college by the time i finish this.

In my code i use the distance between P and the PRP to avoid using bigIntegers. Also i store that in a .txt from which i read and write to. Here is a small part of my code:

```
//Stores PRPs to List<Long> Erros = new ArrayList();

BigInteger Primo = new BigInteger("1");

while (Primo.longValueExact() <= Max){

        while(Erros_Eliminados.size() < 200000){

            Primo = Primo.nextProbablePrime();
            BigInteger R1 = BPrimo_Dado.mod(Primo); //[BPrimo_Dado = P = 8761 Digits number]

            long R = R1.longValue();

            while(R <= Max){ //Max = 250000000

                if(R >= Min){ //Min = 0

                    Erros_Eliminados.add(R);

                }

                R += Primo.longValue();

            }

        }

        ...
        //removes the ErrosEliminados from Erros List and save it again to .txt

}
```

**I also use similars codes for primes between 250M and 1 Billion, and bigger than 1 Billion (Reading from a bitlist) with some slight changes...

So the question is: What is the fastest method to find those big primes numbers? Is there a better way instead of a sieve? I am open for anything...

PS: This is my first question and given my question is kinda weird there is high chance i am breaking a few conduct rules, like being vague or something like that so forgive me if that is the case and please tell so that i can fix anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Feel free to read over some question tips while you wait. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. If you think something is missing, feel free to [edit]

Comment: I might misunderstand your code here but shouldn't the line `BigInteger R1 = BPrimo_Dado.mod(Primo);` be `BigInteger R1 = Primo.subtract(BPrimo_Dado.mod(Primo));` ?

Comment: Why are you doing this? This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: R1 is the mod of BPrimo_Dado or the mod of the 8761 Digits prime. Primo is the primes used in the sieve like 2,3,5,7...n.

Comment: I am doing this because my program may work for finding really big primes if i can get over the time constraints. 8761 digits is already pretty big... No idea what X-Y means though...

Answer (score 2):

The `BigInteger` class can generate large primes for you: `BigInteger.probablePrime()` and also find the next prime: `BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()`.

Comment: Yeah but it takes too long for primes this size. I tested it but i couldnt even get a result before i gave up that...

Comment: I doubt that you can write faster code.  Big numbers can be slow to test, which is why methods like Miller-Rabin are used.

Comment: @BarriaKarl: Look at the source code for `BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()`. It does a sieve of eratosthenes followed by miller-rabin. If you can do better in Java then Oracle would like to have your code.

Comment: Just checked again, 615 minutes to find one prime using .nextProbablePrime(). So not gonna happen...